Prove that for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ do not exist satisfying $x^3+1=4y^2$
Prove that for $x, y \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ do not exist satisfying $x^3+1=4y^2$
$x^3+1=4y^2 \Leftrightarrow (x+1)(x^2-x+1)=(2y)^2$
Put $gcd(x+1,x^2-x+1)=d$
We have $d|x+1$ and $d|x^2-x+1$
$\Rightarrow d|3 \Rightarrow d \in \{ 1;3 \}$
If $d=1 \Rightarrow x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$ are square numbers. 
We have: $x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2\lt x^2-x+1 \lt x^2+2x+1 = (x+1)^2$
$\Rightarrow x^2-x+1=x^2 \Leftrightarrow x=1$
Change $x=1$ to $x^3+1=4y^2$ then we have: $y^2=\frac{2}{4}$ (not satisfied)
I will prove it but I cannot prove that if $d=3$ something absurd happens

More simply:  I would suggest:  $x^3=(2y+1)(2y-1)$ and $\gcd(2y+1,2y-1)=1$.

Let $z=2y$. Then you are looking for solutions to $x^3+1=z^2$. Mihailescu's theorem proves that the only two perfect powers in $\mathbb Z^+$ that differ by $1$ are $8,9$, which would afford $x=2, z=3$, but $z=3\Rightarrow y\not \in \mathbb Z^+$. Hence, there are no solutions as the question is posed.

I would try proving it this way:

First, after noting that $y=1$ is not in any solution, that $y$ must be at least $2$ for any positive integral $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $x^3+1=4y^2$.

Then, assuming that $y$ is an integer at least $2$, note $$x^3 = 4y^2-1 \implies x^3 = (2y-1)(2y+1).$$

Then use the fact that $\gcd(2y-1,2y+1)$ must be $1$ [make sure you see why] to conclude that both $2y-1$ and $2y+1$ must both be cubes if $(2y-1)(2y+1) = x^3$ is itself an integral cube [make sure you see why]. And as $y$ is at least $2$, both $2y-1$ and $2y+1$ are positive and thus both $2y-1$ and $2y+1$ must both be cubes of positive integers.

Then finish by noting that the difference between 2 positive integral cubes is at least $7 > 2 = (2y+1)-(2y-1)$, and so $2y+1$ and $2y-1$ cannot both be cubes, and thus $(2y-1)(2y+1) = x^3$ cannot itself be an integral cube after all.


